# Xcode (from Unity3D) unable to extract archive

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine, testflight

I have an iOs game that I have passed into TestFlight before. but now it has levels in it and it won't work
(As I archive, In the send to Apple: I can see my app has entitlements but the bundle underneath it says 0)
Then the error says

"The package could not be unpacked because of the following error: Unable to extract archive. Please make sure /var/folders/_k/9j..... iPhone.ipa is a valid zip or ipa archive."

Any ideas? 
Thanks

Comment: By the way, my "Application uses iPhone" is set to "Yes"

Comment: Anyone? I've posted on the Dev forum too

Comment: same issue. it works on my phone, but can't submit.

Answer (score 1):

you need to disable plugins for that platform, select plugin folder, and use inspector to disable it for iOS. For me it was the Oculus VR plugin.